# The new command text returns data with schema different from the schema of the main query. Check your query's command text if this is not desired

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, strongly-typed-dataset

`The new command text returns data with schema different from the schema of the main query. Check your query's command text if this is not desired.`

I am getings this warning, when ever i add a query in a `Strongly Typed DataSet` which returns a single column

Ex

```
`SELECT DISTINCT Building
 FROM            Room
 ORDER BY Building
```

when i give this query it will show me a warning.

Because warning leads to a constraint error when ever i call the same function in a windows form

Answer (score 1):

When looking for DISTINCT values, the schema will differ from the MAIN query. The MAIN query usually will envelop the entire structure for hooking up to forms. I (for example) want DISTINCT values from all the records to populate a combo box. This is NOT possible due to schema errors. To suggest the nobody would need to use DISCTINCT values to populate a combo or listbox would be ignorant.

Bottom line, need to create a new TableAdapter, or loop throught the dataset and populate your combo with unique value.

Being able to add multiple queries (Either FillBy, or GetBy) to return rows or single values without have to worry about the schema would solve alot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure this query in your `TableAdapter` to return a scalar(single) value instead of returning rows. Otherwise the `TableAdapter` tries to apply the same schema as in your main query.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233822%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171907.aspx

According to your comment:

"In addition to the standard functionality of a DataAdapter, TableAdapters provide additional typed methods that encapsulate queries that share a common schema with the associated typed DataTable. In other words, you can have as many queries as you want on a TableAdapter **as long as they return data that conforms to the same schema**."

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28VS.80%29.aspx

You either have to create another TableAdapter with different schema(one column) or you keep returning all columns of your main-query and pick that column that you need(f.e. with the [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) property of a ComboBox).

Comment: I dont want to use as Scalar... Since a single column may return many rows

Comment: @kishorejangid: Can i ask why you only need to return one column when your TableAdapter's main query returns multiple? You can simply pick that column that you need(f.e. with the [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) property of a ComboBox).

Comment: The things is in strongly typpe dataset, we will get a default Adapter as `GetData()`. In this table Building i have 7 Columns but i want to list out only the distinct `BuildingNames` column to show them in a `ComboBox` and combobox accept only one column.

Comment: Now you will think that i cant get the column from the `GetData` but if the no of rows in the table increases to thousands in overtime then loading all the column for just building name will make the process slow and waste of memory

Comment: Then create a simple variant of your TableAdapter that only contains few columns. (see my edit)
You could call this `Room` and your old one `RoomDetails`.

Comment: No.., If this is the case then i will have 3 to 4 variants for each table and there are 120 tables..

Comment: You haven't understand. If your datamodel is reasonable normalized, you should not have dozen columns in every table. Normally it does not make a great difference whether you query 1 or 20 columns. So it should be quite exceptional to split your DataTables into a small and a detailed table. But anyway this would be a clean approach.